# Angularjs load module based on conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

i am using angularjs and gulp for my application.
here is my directory structure.

[image]

content of `app.js` is

```
'use strict';
angular.module('BlurAdmin', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.sortable',
    'ui.router',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngStorage',
    'MyApp.theme',
    'MyApp.pages'
]).run(function ($rootScope, $sessionStorage) {
    $rootScope.sessionStorage = $sessionStorage;
});
```

it load page.module.js

content of the `page.module.js` is

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var myApp = angular.module('MyApp.pages', [
        'ui.router',
    ])
    .config(routeConfig);

    /** @ngInject */
    function routeConfig($urlRouterProvider, baSidebarServiceProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');
    }

    var lazyModules = [
        'MyApp.pages.dashboard',
        'MyApp.pages.create',
        'MyApp.pages.otherModule'
    ];

    angular.forEach(lazyModules, function (dependency) {
        myApp.requires.push(dependency);
    });
})();
```

This will load all module as menu item in my page. i want to make it conditional based on type of loggedin users.

for that i have used `$sessionStorage` in `.run` of app.js, but i am not able to use it in pages.module.js

please help me to load module conditional for example if role is admin then only `create` module sould be loaded etc..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try someting like this:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var myApp = angular.module('MyApp.pages', [
    'ui.router',
  ])
  .config(routeConfig)
  .run(lazyModules);

  /** @ngInject */
  function routeConfig($urlRouterProvider, baSidebarServiceProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');
  }

  function lazyModules($sessionStorage) {

    var userModules = [
      'MyApp.pages.dashboard',
      'MyApp.pages.otherModule'
    ];

    var adminModules = [
      'MyApp.pages.create',
      'MyApp.pages.otherModule'
    ];

    var isAdmin = $sessionStorage.admin;
    var loadModules = isAdmin ? adminModules : adminModules;

    angular.forEach(loadModules, function (dependency) {
      myApp.requires.push(dependency);
    });
  }

})();
```

Comment: there is multiple defination for `routeConfig` function, and how u call both?
and param $sessionStorage is comming from where in your `routeConfig` function?

Comment: it loading modules, if i put forEach() outside the `lazyModules` function

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you need [require.js](http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/#/home)
Check role and go to page something like "/admin".

```
    $routeProvider.when("/admin", angularAMD.route({
        templateUrl: 'your.html', controller: 'createController',
        controllerUrl: 'create'
    })).when("/other", angularAMD.route({
        templateUrl: 'your.html', controller: 'otherController',
        controllerUrl: 'other'
    }))
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/808213/Developing-a-Large-Scale-Application-with-a-Single

Comment: there is another sub menu also, so i don't think that will work for me